# what are the commands to reocver EFS encryption keys from the domain recovery agent?

Tags: windows, encryption, windows-server-2012, efs

they are in this video but i can not see the commands would really appreciate if anyone could help , been trying to do this for hours now.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=meQHYNVZYdY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below commands should be the ones not completely 100%
At the command prompt, type Certutil -getkey *********** ############

To target a specific CA rather than all Enterprise CAs type, Certutil -config  -getkey *********** ############

To decrypt type, Certutil  -recoverkey  ############  user.pfx –p password

*********** the serial number of the certificate that should be recovered

######  the file name of the encrypted BLOB that is extracted from the CA database

Comment: What do i put after getkey  where the* are? Also what does a # represent?

Comment: The #is the encrypted BLOB filename

Comment: The * is the serial number for the cetificates you want to recover

Comment: Your the best !!! I have finally done it successfully thank you so much was really struggling with this .

Comment: One final question when i recover the personal certificate for the user it puts a second certificate into the store and i can not figure out what it is any ideas please?